# scdf 2.1 k8s config security context non root no fs writable

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

I need config scdf2 skipper , scdf and app pods to run without root and no write into filesystem pod .

i made changes into config yamls 
data:
  application.yaml: |-
    spring:
      cloud:
        skipper:
          server:
            platform:
              kubernetes:
                accounts:
                  default:
                    namespace: default
                    deploymentServiceAccountName: scdf2-server-data-flow
                    securityContext:
                      runAsUser: 2000
                      allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
                    limits:
Colla

And scdf start runs with user "2000", (there is a problem with writeable local maven repo, fixed with a pvc nfs)...

But, the app pods always starts as root user, no 2000 users.
I've change skipper-config with securitycontext, .. any clues?

TX

Answer (score 0):

What you set as `deploymentServiceAccountName` is one of the [Kubernetes deployer properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#configuration-kubernetes-deployer) that can be used for deploying streaming applications or launching task applications.

Looks like the above configuration is not applied to your SCDF or Skipper server configuration properties as they should at least get applied when deploying applications.

For the SCDF server and Skipper servers, in your SCDF/Skipper server deployment configurations, you need to explicitly set your `serviceAccountName` (not as `deploymentServiceAccountName` as its name suggests, the `deploymentServiceAccountName` is internally converted into the actual `serviceAccountName` for the respective stream/task apps when they get deployed).

Answer (score 0):

We got it. We use it into skipp/scdf deploy, not in pods deploymente.
Your request:

Into scdf / skipper cfg deployment got:

```
spec:
   containers:
     - name: {{ template "scdf.fullname" . }}-server
       image: {{ .Values.server.image }}:{{ .Values.server.version }}
       imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.server.imagePullPolicy }}
       volumeMounts:
       ...
     serviceAccountName: {{ template "scdf.serviceAccountName" . }}
```

Do you tell me to change config map scdf/skipper to task and streams? Another property  into or before config about deployment

How is it relation about "serviceaccount" and user running process into pod?
How related serviceaccount with running process user "2000"

I cant understand.

Please help, it is very important to running without root and no use local filesystem from pod excepts "tmp" files